# Google Cloud Container Registry: Avoiding Duplicate Image Bloat

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I noticed that every Google Cloud Function maintains its own image file in the Google Container Registry, even though all cloud functions share the exact same source code and are just specifying different code-entry points.

Is it possible to deploy different cloud functions, each with their own code entry-point, from just a single container hosted in the Container Registry?

The only way I see this happening right now is by using a single Cloud Function that first routes requests to the correct handler function in-code.

Comment: 1) You will need to route requests. 2) Container images are not a single file. Containers are a collection of layers. Each layer has a HASH value. If two layers have the same HASH only one is stored on disk. I do not know the internals of Container Registry or Artifact Register, but assume that the same physical storage hierarchy is used. 3) The source code that comprises your application will create one or more layers that are combined with other layers to result in the final container image. A single change to a layer will result in a different container image being generated.

Comment: 4) Do you have container bloat? That cannot be determined easily via the Console GUI. Google is presenting a logical view of containers and not the internal details of how they are constructed and stored on disk.

Comment: 5) If you are curious about how containers are constructed, use the `docker save` command. That command will export the files that comprise a container in archive (tar) format. You will be able to see each layer and the files contained in each layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering this as community wiki.As mentioned above in comments by John Hanley.

1. You will need to route requests.
2. Container images are not a single file. Containers are a collection of layers. Each layer has a HASH value. If two layers have the same HASH only one is stored on disk. I do not know the internals of Container Registry or Artifact Register, but assume that the same physical storage hierarchy is used.
3. The source code that comprises your application will create one or more layers that are combined with other layers to result in the final container image. A single change to a layer will result in a different container image being generated.
4. Do you have container bloat? That cannot be determined easily via the Console GUI. Google is presenting a logical view of containers and not the internal details of how they are constructed and stored on disk.
5. If you are curious about how containers are constructed, use the docker save command. That command will export the files that comprise a container in archive (tar) format. You will be able to see each layer and the files contained in each layer.